# How to convert HTML to plaintext in a Flow?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, html

I've set up a Flow that send emails with content of questions asked in Community (we take: `FeedItem.body`). Unfortunately email body can only be plain text. 
Since the questions are often posted in HTML, how to convert HTML body to plaintext body, in my flow?
I do not know Apex at all but if there is a very simple way to put some Apex in my Flow, why not (if it's feasible).

Comment: A flow can call an Apex class to perform actions. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_designer_elements_apex.htm&language=en_US. I think that might be the only way to do this as there is no flow functionality to do this conversion.